# boost python wrap c++ class private member

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-python

Can we wrap c++ private constructor with boost python?
i have a singleton c++ class and want to wrap it to python.

Can we wrap c++ private member function with boost python?

Thanks so much

Comment: What would be the point of doing so? You can't insert Python code into a C++ class, which means that any _useful_ wrapping of the private members would fail to compile. (Whether there's any way to create useless wrappers, I couldn't say… but who cares?)

Comment: @abarmert. I updated my question. hopefully, you see my point

Comment: If you could call the private constructor or private factory function from anywhere, C++ or Python, it wouldn't be a singleton anymore. Just wrap the `getInstance()` method, `getFoo()` function, `g_foo` global, or whatever you'd use to access the singleton in C++.

Comment: yes,but c++ compilation comes out error if i dont do anything about constructor.  for example, if i dont wrap the private constructor, it will say erorr : xxx is private.

Comment: It's very hard to imagine what code you might have written, how you might have wrapped it, and what you might have done wrong. Please create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem so we can help you.

Answer (score 4):

Use something like this:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::python;
using std::cout;

class Singleton
{
    private:
        Singleton()
        {
            cout << "Creating instance\n";
        }
    friend Singleton* create(); 
};

Singleton* pInstance_;
Singleton* create()
{       
    if(!pInstance_)
    {
        pInstance_ = new Singleton();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Using old instance\n";         
    }       
    return pInstance_;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(cppmodule)
{
    def("create", create, return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>());
    class_<Singleton>("Singleton", no_init);
}

/* using singleton later in code */

Singleton* otherInstance_ = create();
```

Session:

```
>>> import cppmodule
Creating instance
>>> s = cppmodule.Singleton()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: This class cannot be instantiated from Python
>>> s = cppmodule.create()
Using old instance
```

Comment: Thanks Nykakin. this is sample good for  python user. but c++ user will be used the Singleton() directly. is it a way to prevent both python user and c++ user to create a new instance?

Comment: @cppython, you have to make Singleton constructor private and make create() function friend of this class. You will be able to create instance only through this function in both Python and C++. I updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

A singleton will often declare its constructors with private visibility, and provide a factory function with access to the private constructor.

```
class singleton
{
public:

  /// @brief Public factory function.
  static singleton& instance()
  {
    static singleton instance_;
    return instance_;
  }

private:

  // Private constructors and destructor.
  singleton()  {}
  ~singleton() {};

  singleton(const singleton&);
  singleton& operator=(const singleton&);
};
```

By default, Boost.Python assumes a publicly available constructor that matches the [init-expression](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/v2/init.html#init-expressions) provided to the [`boost::python::class_`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/v2/init.html#init-expressions) constructor.  To suppress this behavior, the special `boost::python::no_init` object can be provided to the `class_` constructor.  Additionally, due to the private destructor, the `class_` needs to be exposed as noncopyable, by providing `boost::noncopyable` as a template argument.

```cpp
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<singleton, boost::noncopyable>("Singleton", python::no_init);
}
```

In Python, singletons rarely present themselves as singletons through their API.  As such, many Python developers may naturally expect to be able to instantiate the Python class via `example.Singleton()`, rather than using a factor method.  While the default constructors have been exposed via `python::no_init`, a custom constructor can be defined for `__init__`.  To properly account for the C++ singleton, the singleton exposed through Boost.Python will use `boost::shared_ptr` with a no-operation deleter to hold a handle to the singleton.  Here is a complete example:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

/// @brief Mock up singleton class.
class singleton
{
public:
  /// @brief Public factory function.
  static singleton& instance()
  {
    static singleton instance_;
    return instance_;
  }

  void set_x(unsigned int x) { x_ = x;    }
  unsigned int get_x()       { return x_; }

private:

  // Private constructors and destructor.
  singleton() : x_(0) {}
  ~singleton() {};

  singleton(const singleton&);
  singleton& operator=(const singleton&);

private:
  unsigned int x_;
};

/// @brief No operation deleter.
void noop_deleter(void*) {};

/// @brief Helper function used to get a shared_ptr that holds
///        a singleton.
boost::shared_ptr<singleton> py_get_singleton()
{
  return boost::shared_ptr<singleton>(
    &singleton::instance(), // the instance
    &noop_deleter);         // no-op deleter
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  // Expose the singleton class, supressing the default constructor
  // via python::no_init, and providing a constructor that will return
  // a handle to the singleton.
  python::class_<singleton, boost::shared_ptr<singleton>,
                 boost::noncopyable>("Singleton", python::no_init)
    .def("__init__", python::make_constructor(&py_get_singleton))
    .add_property("x", &singleton::get_x, &singleton::set_x)
    ;
}
```

And its usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> s1 = example.Singleton()
>>> s2 = example.Singleton()
>>> s1.x
0
>>> s2.x
0
>>> s1.x = 5
>>> s2.x
5
```

Note that from a Python perspective, this is more akin to the borg or monostate pattern, as they share state, rather than identity.  (I.e. `s1.x == s2.x`, but `id(s1) != id(s2)`.)  If the Python class needs to be a singleton as well, rather than just its state, then it may be necessary to implement this behavior with Python code, rather than C++.